# Why is my Azure Function not being triggered by blob storage trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless-framework

Some project demands at work have necessitated the need for us to use Azure. While I have a lot of experience with AWS, I have zero experience with Azure, and I am at a loss as to why my Azure Function is not being run.

tl;dr - We have some logs being written to a storage account. We want to copy those logs to AWS S3 for longer term storage (due to compliance reasons). The best long term/scalable solution for this is to just copy the file when it's created via an Azure Function, similar to how you'd execute a Lambda when a file is written to S3.

Due to my lack of knowledge in Azure, I decided to use Serverless Framework to get up and running quickly. The following is my `serverless.yml`:

```yaml
---

service: export-logs-to-aws-s3

provider:
  name: azure
  location: East US
  runtime: nodejs18
  environment:
    AzureWebJobsREDACTEDStorage: "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=REDACTED;AccountKey=REDACTED;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

plugins:
  - serverless-azure-functions

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - .gitignore
    - package.json
    - .git/**

functions:
  exportToS3:
    handler: handler.exportToS3
    events:
      - blob: true
        name: item
        path: "insights-activity-logs/{name}"
        connection: REDACTEDStorage
```

The actual function itself is somewhat irrelevant for this question as it's just about getting the function to trigger, but all it's doing right now is console logging out the file.

The above deploys successfully. I can see it in Azure, trigger is all there and setup. This is the `function.json` that is generated,

```json
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "item",
      "path": "insights-activity-logs/{name}",
      "connection": "REDACTEDStorage"
    }
  ],
  "entryPoint": "exportToS3",
  "scriptFile": "../handler.js"
}
```

On the storage account that I'm trying to copy files from, a.k.a. have trigger the function, a.k.a.k.a. the one specified in "AzureWebJobsREDACTEDStorage", I have given the Azure Function App identity role assignments of "Storage Blob Data Owner" and "Storage Queue Data Contributor" as per the documentation.

Every time I add a file manually into the "insights-activity-logs" container, nothing happens. Nothing is triggered. I've poured over the documentation and I'm coming up short.

**Any ideas? Anything blatantly obvious that I'm missing?**

It's also worth noting that Serverless Framework appears to deploy using version `~3` for "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION". Not sure why this is, but it does. I know the docs mentioned version 5 a lot.

Comment: I can give you an example of Azure Functions python Blob trigger copying blob from one blob to another when file is uploaded in one blob, You can implement same logic with your Amazon S3 is it fine?

Comment: You can use this GitHub repository which might meet your requirement- https://github.com/nianton/azstorage-to-s3

Comment: According to the Answer here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/827616/azure-function-to-download-blobs-and-upload-the-da > there's no direct output binding in azure functions that connects to AWS S3, As a workaround you can use the github link I shared in previous comment or You will have to use the AWS S3 SDK - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingAWSSDK.html to upload the blobs to S3 bucket. available output bindings -https://i.imgur.com/pUnDAMU.png